# Code Coverage for Mono?

Tags: mono, code-coverage, ncover

mono creates its own debug targets called .mdb files when you use the mcs compiler.

is there a way of using NCover or another code coverage tool with Mono?

a commandline tool would be better so I can add it to our continuous integration server.

Comment: I can't really understand why this was closed. Since I've basically started work recently on XR.Baboon which is a proper line-by-line code coverage tool for mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you looked into [monocov](http://www.mono-project.com/Code_Coverage)?

Comment: looks like it'll work, shame theres only a source distro

Comment: looks like the dependencies are a mess, I'm going to try to compile it again on the weekend